# Is it possible to create a starter Gruntfile programatically?

Tags: bash, gruntjs

For example you can create a starter package.json file programatically using:

```
sudo npm init
```

Can this be done to create a starter Gruntfile.js, similar to something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
  });
};
```

Comment: You might be looking for something like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which generates 'scaffolding' or boilerplate code for your application. Particularly, you may want [generator-gruntfile](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gruntfile) from the Yeoman team. Alternatively you could try [grunt-init](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding).

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers to your questions (by clicking the green tick) if they helped you - it will give you a small rep bonus for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways that you can create a Gruntfile by default, depending on the needs of your project:

### grunt-init

[`grunt-init`](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding) is a tool provided by Grunt itself to generate a Gruntfile and directory structure. To generate just a Gruntfile, you can use the [`grunt-init-gruntfile`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile) template, with the following commands:

```
npm install -g grunt-init
git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile.git ~/.grunt-init/gruntfile
grunt-init gruntfile
```

This will generate a directory structure like [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile-sample/tree/generated) after asking you [these questions](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile-sample#project-creation-transcript):

> [?] Is the DOM involved in ANY way? (Y/n)
>
> [?] Will files be concatenated or minified? (Y/n)
>
> [?] Will you have a package.json file? (Y/n)
>
> [?] Do you need to make any changes to the above before continuing? (y/N)

### Yeoman

For more advanced projects, you can use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/index.html), which has many generators for various typical projects. For example, if you're creating an Angular project, you can use [`generator-angular`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). You'll find the instructions on how to use it at the Yeoman site, so I won't repeat them unnecessarily here.